# Ansible Playbook that will run a query on a postgres SQL db instance

Tags: ansible

I am new to using Ansible and am looking to understand how to write an Ansible Playbook that will run a query on a postgres SQL db instance as a particular user and display the output in the terminal.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM example_db;
```

Could someone provide a simple example?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Christofides' example. I made some modifications and tested.
 this works:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  tasks:
    - name: Select all from example table
      command: psql -c "SELECT * FROM example_table" example_db
      register: select_all_from_example

    - name : Display example table contents
      debug: msg="{{ select_all_from_example.stdout }}"
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Nice !  thanks yantaq!  This did indeed work.  I'll just need to work on the formatting but it looks pretty  promising

Answer (score 2):

This is an untested example which shows the essentials. It may require tweaking depending on your setup.

```
- name: Select all from example table
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: postgres
  command: psql -c "SELECT * FROM example_table" example_db
  register: select_all_from_example

- name: Display example table contents
  debug: msg="{{ select_all_from_example.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new role that provides four new modules:

- postgresql_table: ensure that a table is present (or absent) in
  database
- postgresql_row: ensure that a row is present (or absent) in a table
- postgresql_query: execute an arbitrary query in database and
  return results
- postgresql_command: execute an arbitrary query in
  database

Look here for docs: https://github.com/rtshome/ansible_pgsql

Answer (score 0):

Using Ansible Shell Module

To create Database and User

Here I am creating : `airflow` db, user `airflow_user` and password `airflow_password`

Set postgres_user(the main user) password in `PGPASSWORD` variable

```
  - name: Created Airflow Database and User in Postgres
    shell: /usr/bin/psql --host=10.0.0.39  --dbname=postgres --username=postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE airflow" ; /usr/bin/psql --host=10.0.0.39  --dbname=postgres --username=postgres -c "CREATE USER airflow_user WITH PASSWORD 'airflow_password'" ;  /usr/bin/psql --host=10.0.0.39  --dbname=postgres --username=postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE airflow TO airflow_user " ;
    environment:
      PGPASSWORD: postgres_password
    register: postgres_query_status
    failed_when: "'already exists' not in postgres_query_status.stderr and  'CREATE' not in postgres_query_status.stdout"
    tags:
    - postgres
```